# InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:Parameter value did not match expected type

Tags: spring-data-jpa

please can you help me with the following exception:  org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [myCalendar] did not match expected type [pl.sda.jira.calendar.domain.model.Name (n/a)].

I'm having difficulty fixing this error. Grateful if you could let me know what options I have.

The test where I get the error:

```
@Test
public void shouldGetCalendarEqualToName() throws Exception {

    MockHttpServletResponse response = restClient.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/calendars")
                    .param("columnName", "name")
                    .param("type", "equals")
                    .param("value", "myCalendar"))
            .andReturn().getResponse();
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), response.getStatus());
    assertEquals("[{\"name\":\"calendar0\",\"owner\":\"Jon\"}]", response.getContentAsString());

}
```

My QueryService (pasting only the applicable case from the switch-case):

```
private Specification<Calendar> createSpecificationsFrom(QueryCriteriaDto queryCriteriaDto) {
    switch (queryCriteriaDto.getType()) {
        case "equals":
            return ((root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) ->
                    criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(queryCriteriaDto.getColumnName()), (queryCriteriaDto.getValue())));
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

My class Name:

```
public class Name {
private String value;

public Name(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String value() {
    return value;
}}
```

I'm also using a Converter:

```
@Converter   
public class NameConverter implements AttributeConverter<Name, String> {

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Name name) {
    return name.value();
}

@Override
public Name convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
    return new Name(value);
}}
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace (formatted as code if please). This looks like it is coming from the call to a repository method. Please post the code calling that method.

Comment: If you fixed the problem, please either properly answer your question yourself or delete the question when it was something like a typo that most likely won't help anybody.

Comment: @JensSchauder Thank you, I have fixed this one. In the createSpecificationsFrom() I replaced: queryCriteriaDto.getValue() with: new Name(queryCriteriaDto.getValue().

Comment: Cool, please post it as a proper answer instead of just a comment. In a few days you can even accept the answer.